# Cutting and pasting controls into TabControl created new functions

Tags: c#

We created a new tab and moved the controls from the form into the Tab by cutting and pasting.

This prevented using the old functions. Instead, it created new ones. Is there any way to use the same old functions in the new tab?

PS: Also undo function is not available so that we cannot go back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a cut and paste. IDE removes the bindings of controls with events. To re-bind the controls with same events you can do this

YourControl-->properties-->events--> and select the appropriate function (that is already present) to bind with